# How to give dial functionality to the icon

Tags: html, css, dialing

I need to do whenever click on number or dial icon it's going to dialing in our mobile.

I have done whenever click on number it's going to dial, but I don't no how to give same for the icon.

```css
.contact-list {
 background: #fff;
 background-size: 30px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px; //
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-list" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
  <h2>Fire</h2>
  <p>
   <span><a data-rel="external"
    data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588"
    style="color: #333946; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;">974-4433665588</a></span>
   <span><img src="img/contact.png" alt="974-4433665588" style="width: 28px;float: right;margin-top: -19px !important;margin-right: 13px;" /></span>
  </p>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Just place your `<a>` tag across all dashed region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the icon in an `a` tag see below:

```
    <div class="contact-list" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
            <h2>Fire</h2>
            <p>
                <span><a data-rel="external"
                    data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588"
                    style="color: #333946; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;">974-4433665588</a></span>
                <span><a href="tel:974-4433665588">
<img src="img/contact.png" alt="974-4433665588" style="width: 28px;float: right;margin-top: -19px !important;margin-right: 13px;" /></a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the image into a link (`<a>` tag).

```html
<a data-rel="external" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
   <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/phone-call_318-62608.png" alt="974-4433665588" class="phone-image"/>
</a>
```

Here is the complete code:

```css
.contact-list {
  background: #fff;
  background-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px; //
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}
.phone-label {
  color: #333946;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.phone-image {
  width: 28px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-list" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
  <h2>Fire</h2>
  <p>
    <span>
      <a data-rel="external" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588" class="phone-label">974-4433665588</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a data-rel="external" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/phone-call_318-62608.png" alt="974-4433665588" class="phone-image"/>
      </a>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated putting the `<a>` tags around the div will solve the problem.

But while I was looking at it, I thought I'd move it around a little and introduce you to [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) which is very helpful for styling.

It's always best to have a css file rather than to do styles inline. it looks neater and it's easier to change (as you just do it once even if the style is repeated)

```css
.phone-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contact-list {
  background: #fff;
  background-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.phone-no h2 {
  color: #000;
}
.phone-no {
  color: #333946;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.phone-icon {
  margin: 13px;
}
.filler {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<a data-rel="external" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588" class="phone-link">
  <div class="contact-list" data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588">
    <span class="phone-no">
      <h2>Fire</h2>
      974-4433665588
    </span>
    <span class="filler"></span>
    <span class="phone-icon">
      <img src="http://www.toyotaoftricities.com/assets/d1123/img/phone_icon.png" alt="974-4433665588" />
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
<a data-rel="external" data-tel="974-1223344556" href="tel:974-1223344556" class="phone-link">
  <div class="contact-list" data-tel="974-1223344556" href="tel:974-1223344556">
    <span class="phone-no">
      <h2>Police</h2>
      974-1223344556
    </span>
    <span class="filler"></span>
    <span class="phone-icon">
      <img src="http://www.toyotaoftricities.com/assets/d1123/img/phone_icon.png" alt="974-4433665588" />
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```